# Regex matches substring a wrong string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that matches capital and short letters , starts with a capital letter, optionally has an apostrophe and could accept accented characters.

[A-Z]+\'?[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]*

Example of strings that has to be matched:
Jon Ross
James Smith
John Wayne
Jay Wualà

The problem is that it matches substrings in wrong strings, as
John-Wayne
It only matches "John" and "Wayne" but I want the entire string not matched. What am I wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$` and `^` to match beginning and end of string:

```
^[A-Z]+\'?[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]*$
```

This will mean it'll only match the entire string.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it seems working. If I want to add a space, only 1 space, how can I modify that?
^[A-Z]+\'?[\sa-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]*$
I tried in this way but it matches the entire line, not only one space

Comment: For matching a single space, you can't put the \s inside the character set brackets, because when you do that the * at the end applies to it.  You need to do something like ^[A-Z]+\'?[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]*(?:\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]*)$ instead.  You may be able to make it more elegant.